# Not able to reach Iframe

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

[image][image]Here is my HTML:

```
<iframe id="3093bab4-296d-4f37-8041-ce4f78358f44" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%" allowtransparency="true" src="http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions#functionId=S.01100202304.00&amp;reqId=2b5b69f9-1f44-4c5d-9313-b6cc5d570f5e" cd_frame_id_="bcd064222ffff8919b77d7a162b6e1fe"></iframe>
```

I am actually trying to click one button "Post" which is under this frame but getting the below exception :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\Package_1\CashManagement.py", line 119, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']")))
  File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

This is I am trying :

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']")))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]")).click()
```

Can anybody tell me , whats wrong ? thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a `css_selector` not `xpath` :

try this :

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']")))
```

also make sure that you are not in any iframe prior to this, if you are, you should switch to default content like this :

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Comment: sorry guys! This is still giving  error :

Comment: Error Message :  File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\Package_1\CashManagement.py", line 121, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']")))
  File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: Are you sure, if that's the right css ? Did you check in dev tool ? Do we have 1/1 matching node ? Also as mentioned, try switching to default content if you are already in the different iframe

Comment: I have switched t default already .. and the switching to this.. is there anyway i can post screenshot here ?

Comment: You can update your question with the appropriate screenshots.

Comment: No, You need to write `iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']` to see if we have matching node.

Comment: See the second screen

Comment: no, that looks unstable, when you write this `iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']` what do you see ? Are you sure `POST` button is in the above iframe.

Comment: Yes Post is in the Iframe for sure,  this is the error:   File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\Package_1\CashManagement.py", line 121, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']")))
  File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: okay webdriver wait will always raise common exceptions that is TimeoutException,  we will never get to know. So I would suggest try running this `driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']"))` and see what is the actual error.

Comment: Here is the new error :   File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\Package_1\CashManagement.py", line 122, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src*='http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions']']"))
  File "C:\Users\kenaik\PycharmProjects\gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {

Comment: Does not look like entire error stack trace, cause it does not contain what is the actual error

Comment: Hello, this issue is solved.. Later I realised that it was noy switching the frame.. so driver.switch_to.default_content() was not needed :) Silly me .. but appreciate your help guys.. you rock

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong locator syntax.
Try this:

```
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[contains(@src,'http://gksdc-tst.pvhcorp.com:50100/pvh-pos-server/functions')]")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much .. it worked but its giving error on     wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]")).click()
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given                                                 Is this because of the wrong Xpath ?

Comment: As I see this refers to `__init__()`. You didn't share here all your relevant code, so I can't know. But this is definitely not caused by  `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]")).click()` itself since this command itself is correct

Comment: @Prophet : an open and closing parenthesis is missing in the above comment, causing an error what OP has shared already.

Comment: Maybe you are right. @KetakiNaik please try adding parenthesis there so the command will be `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[contains(text(),'Post')]"))).click()`