# AttributeError while attempting to grab table from a website in Python BS

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I am not sure if this snippet works with this url or page. I tried running the script in the url but I am getting an AttributeError.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C://Python38/chromedriver')
browser.get("https://poocoin.app/rugcheck/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371/top-holders")
url = "https://poocoin.app/rugcheck/0xe56842ed550ff2794f010738554db45e60730371/top-holders"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
t = soup.find('table', class_='table table-bordered table-condensed text-small')
trs = t.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
for tr in trs[:10]:
    print(list(tr.stripped_strings))
browser.quit()
```

Current Output/Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/Acer/poocoin.py", line 8, in <module>
    trs = t.find('tbody').find_all('tr')
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the table fully depends on javascript. I also used  HTMLSession with BeautifulSoup and didn't get any error along with no output. If you prefer to selenium with scrapy then I can help you. Thanks

Comment: Any idea from you will be very helpful. Its very welcome. Thank you in advance

Comment: The url contains iframe

Comment: Any idea how I can extract the data? Can you share the iframe link? Sorry, Im struggling with this.

Comment: [iframe image]: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIxOE.png)

Comment: This  url the "poocoin.app" contains iframe

Comment: [iframe in DOM]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkRAO.png

Comment: is it possible to scrap this?

Comment: sure ! using selenium

Comment: Actually nothing is wrong. The url shows data  but data is generating from iframe and iframe  element to be grabbed using automation tools like selenium from this url.

Comment: [Helpful link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68631585/how-to-click-a-in-a-webpage-without-class-name-or-id-or-with-python-selenium/68631653#68631653)

Comment: [Another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68591081/not-able-to-reach-iframe)